# How to trigger touch event on mouse click in GeckoFX using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, geckofx

I have been trying to trigger a touch event that is restricting me to perform click, as the function is prepared for Smart Phones.

Here is the function that I need to be called on click event using GeckoFX.

```js
$('#next_button,#bottom_next_button,#next_arrow,.image_inner_a').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    if (e.touches && e.touches[0].pageX > 5) {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/[&?]z=[^&]*/, '');
        valid_user = true;
    }
});
```

What I have so far is written below.

```c#
  GeckoElement clickedElement = e.Target.CastToGeckoElement();             
  if (xpathvalue != null) {
      GeckoHtmlElement element = (GeckoHtmlElement)browser.Document.GetSingleElement(xpathvalue);
      if (element != null)
      {
          element.Click();
      }
  }
```

> If there is way to use JavaScript for calling the touch event, it would be accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a custom type of event.
Look at the event documentation here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Then initialize the event:

```
nsAStringBase eventType = new nsAString(eventName.ToLower());
            DomEventArgs ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent(eventTypeName);
            ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, true, false);
```

And then try dispatching the event on a proper element

```
element.DispatchEvent(ev);
```